# Rails devise override action routes generated in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

While using Rails 4.1 with Devise 3.3.0 I noticed the following:

When using routes.rb such as

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/login', :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get '/logout', :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get '/sign_up', :to => "devise/registrations#new"
  end
```

And then on the view of one of these actions:

```
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

The href path to each generated links to the default Devise paths for each action,
such as /users/sign_in instead of /login.

How can you override these default paths to ones you specify?

Answer (score 0):

Add this below the above code in your routes. Hope it works now.

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions"}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask devise to generate the views:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

This will create the _links.html.erb file into your app, so you can update it to use your own routes.

Comment: Doing this doesn't override the default behavior such as a failed login attempt redirects back to /users/sign_in rather than my specified '/sign_in'. I would like devise to completely forget about it's /users path structure.